# How to get orders with other Sales Channel in Amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon MWS https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01
I've multiple accounts, one in each Amazon (Amazon.co.uk, Amazon.de, Amazon.fr, etc)

I'm querying OrderList by API

`$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();`

This request gives me all orders in each Amazon if `SalesChannel` is the same.
For example, I'm querying with `AmazonFR` credentials new orders, and I get result only with orders with `SalesChannes: Amazon.fr`

But there is many other orders with different `SalseChannel`s.
I can see them in `web interface` of `Amazon.fr`, and they looks like:
See `Sales channel: Amazon.it` (italian Amazon in Amazon.fr website)

```
405-2431510-XXXXXXXX
Product Title
QTY: 1  ASIN: 1957306452    SKU: 10-40271
Contact Buyer: Nasty
Sales channel: Amazon.it
Fulfilment method: Seller
Standard

Expected dispatch date
13 Feb 2017

Deliver by
15 Feb 2017 to
28 Feb 2017
Unshipped (1)
```

How can I get also these orders with other `Sales Channel` by API?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found.

Provide an array of `MarketplaceId` to query, and you will get order list with other salses channels.